# Google Sheets conditional formatting based on a series of values in a range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

I want to set conditional formatting for a range based on whether the values of a cell match any value in another range.

I currently accomplish this by using OR:

```
=OR($C4=$F$4,$C4=$F$5,$C4=$F$6,$C4=$F$7)
```

Is there a way to do this without setting each cell in the reference range individually?
If so, would the same formula work for TEXT instead of values? Sample sheet linked below: conFor tab.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Z98qH07-r2Q_Q9IHzKVinLbLPaVbghskU61G0egiWz0/edit#gid=1336453380

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
=not(iserror(MATCH(B4,$F$4:$F$7,0)))
```

#### Reference:

- [MATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378?hl=en)

Comment: thanks. i got it to work with just the MATCH core (which i initially tried but couldn't make work before). working version:
```=MATCH($B4,$F$4:$F$7,0)```